# Select virtual column as percentage

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select virtual column as percentage of another column with the record having greatest value being 100%?

```
Example:

+------------------------------+
| tbl_test                     |
+------------------------------+
| id | col_x | value | percent |
+------------------------------+
|  1 |     a |     2 |      25 |
|  2 |     b |     5 |    62.5 |
|  3 |     c |     8 |     100 |
|  4 |     d |     3 |    37.5 |
+------------------------------+
```

As you can see 8 became the 100% and the rest are calculated as a percentage of 8.

```
SELECT * , () as percent
FROM tbl_test
```

Answer (score 0):

To do something like that, you first need to know what the 100% is:

```
SELECT MAX(value) AS hperc FROM tbl_test;
```

Once that is known, you can divide the other values by this 100%:

```
SELECT *, value/(SELECT MAX(value) AS hperc FROM tbl_test)*100 AS percent
FROM tbl_test;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done in TSQL:

```
select @max = max(value) from tbl_test
select *, cast(value/@max * 100 as decimal(18,2)) as [percent]
from tbl_test
```